Integer Factorization and Number Field Discriminant
Suppose we have an efficient method to construct a number field $K = Q(\alpha) \cong Q[x]/(f)$, defined by a polynomial $f$ of arbitrary degree $d$, such that the discriminant of $K$ is divisible by a prescribed integer $N$ of unknown factorization, and such that the coefficients of $f$ are of size $O(N^{2/(d+1)})$.
The small size of the coefficients of $f$ may give certain computational advantages.  It is clear that it improves the possibility of finding relations in the ideal class group of $K$.  By this understand that the norm of a principal ideal $(a + b\alpha)$ is more likely to be small than if the coefficients of $f$ were large, therefore more likely to factor into small primes and produce a relation for the purpose of computing the class group of $K$.
A similar intuition applies to computing the unit group of $K$.
If we can compute the class group and unit group of $K$, does this help in any way to find the primes which divide the discriminant of $K$, which will include the prime factors of $N$?
Note that in the imaginary quadratic case, the factors of the discriminant correspond to elements of order 2 in the class group.  Also in the real quadratic case the factors of the discriminant can be found by traversing the `infrastructure' of the field using Shanks's SQUFOF algorithm.  Can anything be said of a connection between the factors of the discriminant and structures in higher degree fields?
